# Entity synonyms in Training Data when using RASA NLU

Tags: rasa-nlu

I have created a restaurant bot using python using some Training Data(common_Examples). Till now it's fine, but there are many intents with some similarity.

While i'm going through the RASA_NLU site, I have recognized a number of entity_synonyms that could be useful. I can't seem to find any examples on the web. Specifically, I'm looking for example usage or material on entity_synonyms. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I found a tutorial explaining how entity synonyms can be used.
It uses a json entity synonym file and loads it into the rasa nlu.

[Building a chatbot using rasa stack intro and tips](https://hackernoon.com/building-a-chatbot-using-rasa-stack-intro-and-tips-c6d1057d8536#1fe9)

Also for general usage of entity synonyms you can refer the official documentation they have an example there

https://nlu.rasa.com/dataformat.html?highlight=entity%20synonyms#entity-synonyms

Comment: I have followed this format:
  "rasa_nlu_data": {
    "common_examples": [
      {     "text":"I want to look up Chinese restaurant", "intent":"Rest_srch",  "entity":[{"start":19,"value":"chinese","end":26}]    } ] } }         How to use entity-synonym in it.

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at how [Chatito](https://rodrigopivi.github.io/Chatito/) translates training sentences into a rasa-compliant JSON. It's pretty staightforward, and documented as well.

Besides, I would recommend this tool for the whole training of your bot, not just to learn Rasa syntax.